# Spring @Transactional and concurrency

Tags: java, spring, jpa, concurrency, transactions

I have a Spring controller with the following method:

```
    @PostMapping("/tables")
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public ResponseEntity<Table> addTable(@RequestBody Table table) {
        if (table.getTableNumber() == 0) {
            table.setTableNumber(tableRepository.count() + 1);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(tableRepository.save(table), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

I would like multiple invocations to happen sequentially, so that at every invocation the `count` method will return the correct number of rows (at the moment it doesn't happen, because multiple invocations can run concurrently).

I tried to figure out the best way to do so, and I came to these conclusions (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1. Using `@Transactional` doesn't help, as multiple transactions can still run concurrently
2. Anyway, `@Transactional` will prevent a complex method to persist only a portion of the data when `save` is called multiple times (this isn't the case)
3. `isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` only determines how the new transaction relates to the ones that already finished (in this case, the new transaction would see the DB in its newest form)

I read that I could use a lock with `@Lock` to have exclusive access to a table, but I only saw it applied to single methods (like `findById`), while in my case the lock would have to span multiple operations (the `count` and the `save`). Is there a way to lock a table arbitrarily (either using annotations or programmatically)? Locking an entire table may seem a bit drastic, but at least methods operating on different tables could still run concurrently (this cannot be achieved just by using `synchronized` at the method level, while it would be possible by locking on the repositories, but it definitely doesn't seem a clean job).

It sounds strange that Spring doesn't offer a simple way to say "ehi, I want this method operating on this repository to run only from a thread at once". Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I simplified the method for the question. From what I understand, I should rely on functionalities provided by the DB (for example, constraints) along with transactions to prevent nasty things from happening even in the case of a concurrent modification. I also understand that transactionality and concurrency are not the same thing (that's why I wrote what I understood so far in the question), but I see the two problems to be somewhat related, that's why I mentioned both. I'd still like to understand how I could make operations on the DB sequential.

Comment: I know that in this particular case it isn't necessary to make the calls sequential, as I could make it work in other ways (as you said), I just wanted to show an example involving more than one operations on the same table to show how `@Transactional` isn't helpful in preventing concurrent access (and also to make sure that I understood it correctly) and to understand how to make it work without changing the logic of that code.

Comment: A transaction is not a lock, but they are meant to guarantee data integrity (in various levels, depending on isolation). I suggest you read up on different isolation levels, and see how `SERIALIZABLE` behaves in a conflict situation. This has nothing to do with Spring, JPA or even Java really.

Comment: @NathanHughes it seems that `@Lock` doesn't work with `count` (I think it's because the lock only occurs when a Entity is returned). However, it works with `findAll` and `findById`, which I could use to obtain what I want. The main drawback is the need to redefine all these methods in the repositories and, most importantly, the need to call these methods inside a transaction to make them actually lock the table. I'd like to do so even outside of a transaction. I found some ways (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56530057/3328545)) but it seems very hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about `@Transactional` in that it pertains to a single request and not to multiple requests.

You have a few options available to you here:

1. Move this "locking" to the database layer by writing atomic queries. For example: `update tbl set tableNumber = tableNumber + 1 where id = X` will ensure that multiple concurrent requests will return the right values. In this case, the DB is performing a row level WRITE lock to ensure data consistency.
2. Use a lock. This is as simple as setting a flag in a table in the DB. Before any thread starts with this flow of operation, it checks if the flag is set/unset. If unset, it sets the flag and continues. If unset, the thread waits and polls the value till it reads an unset value. Using something like Redis is a better idea for locking implementations because of call backs on lock expiry.

Using a lock is better because you can then a thread can keep the lock for as long as required (remember to have a `max_timeout`) and touch as many entities as required during this time period.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What is the best way to obtain a lock? Obviously I can do it by manually writing a query, but it doesn't seem an elegant solution.